# Как закрыть тред при выходе из Tkinter-приложения?

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter

Имеется Tkinter-приложение, в котором есть:

- Основное окно
- Дополнительное окно, которое запускается в отдельном треде. Оно содержит кнопку Panic.

Задача проста: при завершении работы программы любым способом (например, по сочетанию Alt+F4), нужно корректно завершить программу.

Я сделал минимальный пример. При завершении его работы появляется ошибка:

```
Запускается тред для окна с кнопкой остановки
Внутри треда с окном-кнопкой Panic
Устанавливается флаг на остановку треда с кнопкой Panic
Завершен тред _threadCodeSmallWindow
Тред с кнопкой Panic полностью завершен

Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
Аварийный останов
```

То есть, нужно, чтобы этой ошибки не возникало.

Если в примере закомментировать последнюю команду **main.destroySmallWindow()**, то ошибки не будет. Но и программа не будет завершаться по Alt+F4, потому что не завершен тред с дополнительным окном.

Я пробовал перед вызовом **rootWindow.mainloop()** добавить команду:

```
rootWindow.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", onDeleteWindow)
```

И функцию при закрытии писал такую:

```
def onDeleteWindow():
    main.destroySmallWindow() # Завершение треда
    rootWindow.destroy() # Закрытие основного окна
```

Но и тогда все равно ошибка сохраняется.

**Вопрос:** как корректно завершить программу?

***Код рабочего примера:***

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
import time
from threading import Thread, Event

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.stopThreadFlag = Event()
        self.smallWindow = None
        self.threadSmallWindow = None

        # Инициализация базового класса рамки
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent)

        # Основная рамка
        frame = tk.Frame(self, relief=tk.RAISED, borderwidth=1)
        frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Надпись
        label = tk.Label(frame, text="Содержимое окна")
        label.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        # Создается окошко-кнопка с кнопкой Panic в отдельном потоке
        self._createSmallWindow()


    # Создание окошка с кнопкой Panic в отдельном потоке
    def _createSmallWindow(self):
        print("Запускается тред для окна с кнопкой остановки")
        self.stopThreadFlag.clear() # Очищается флаг прекращения работы потока
        self.threadSmallWindow = Thread(target = self._threadCodeSmallWindow)
        self.threadSmallWindow.start()


    # Код, выполняемый внутри треда
    def _threadCodeSmallWindow(self):
        print("Внутри треда с окном-кнопкой Panic")

        # Создается окошко с кнопкой Panic
        self.smallWindow= tk.Tk() # = tk.Toplevel(Parameter().rootWindow)
        self.smallWindow.resizable(0, 0) # Запрещает изменение размера
        self.smallWindow.overrideredirect(1) # Отключается все оформление окона

        smallWindowFrame = tk.Frame( self.smallWindow )
        smallWindowFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        button=tk.Button(smallWindowFrame, text="Panic", borderwidth=0, relief=tk.FLAT)
        button.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, anchor="center", expand=True)

        self.smallWindow.update() # Прорисовка окна с кнопкой Panic

        # Вместо mainloop() используется цикл, который завершается при установке флага
        while not self.stopThreadFlag.is_set():
            if self.smallWindow != None:

                # ... Всякие действия ...

                time.sleep(0.5) # Разгрузка работы, чтобы не выжирался весь процессор

        if self.smallWindow != None:
            self.smallWindow.destroy()

        print("Завершен тред _threadCodeSmallWindow")


    # Уничтожение окна и треда с кнопкой Panic
    def destroySmallWindow(self):
        if self.smallWindow != None:
            print("Устанавливается флаг на остановку треда с кнопкой Panic")
            self.stopThreadFlag.set()

            self.threadSmallWindow.join() # Ожидание завершения треда с кнопкой Panic
            print("Тред с кнопкой Panic полностью завершен")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Запуск Tk-подсистемы графических виджетов и создание основного окна
    rootWindow = tk.Tk()
    rootWindow.geometry("320x200+0+0")

    # Создание основной рамки с интерфейсом приложения
    main = MainFrame( rootWindow )
    main.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    # Основной цикл GUI-интерфейса
    rootWindow.mainloop()

    # Вызов завершения треда с окошком Panic
    # Без этого вызова программа не завершится
    main.destroySmallWindow()
```

Comment: Я предположу, что тут вообще не нужен отдельный тред, а нужно переделать бесконечный цикл с паузой в вызов функции через root.after